# Updating a controller's scope using a directive's method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dropzone.js

How can I use a method in a directive to update a variable in the controller's scope?

I am using: [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and [angular-dropzone.js](https://github.com/sandbochs/angular-dropzone).

One of Dropzone's methods is `.getQueuedFiles()`. I would like to use this method to update a variable in the controller scope, but it isn't working. I would like to be able to update controller scope so I can show and hide things and pass the number of files to the next step in the form.

Here is the angular:

```
.controller('ImagesCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.queuedFiles = 0;

  $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
    init: function() {
      this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        $scope.queuedFiles = $scope.dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length;
      });
    }
  };

})
```

And here is the html:

```
<form class="dropzone clear"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    ng-dropzone
    dropzone="dropzone"
    dropzone-config="dropzoneConfig">
</form>

<div>Queued Files: {{queuedFiles}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'myApp.controllers']).
    config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'admin.html',
            onEnter: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log("Entered Admin route");
            }
            //controller: 'myController'
        })
        .state('sitebinding', {
            url: '/sitebinding',
            templateUrl: 'sitebinding.html'
        })
        .state('scrum', {
            url: '/scrum',
            templateUrl: 'scrum.html'
        });


    }
]);


angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.models = {
        helloAngular: 'I work!'
    };

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log('In state change start');
    })
});
```

This is the problem: when you write angular.module('myApp', []) specifying dependencies the second time to define your controllers, you override the original module.

If you want to add new stuff the an existing module you don't need to pass the dependencies array

angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', function....